# use a certain part of the string. A part before and after certain criteria in python

Tags: python

I have an array of full path files for example:

```
a=['/dir1/europe_2013_info.csv', '/dir2/USA_2013_info.csv', '/dir3/Africa_2013_info.csv']
```

I want to create a new file and write this characteristic into this file. for example:

```
f=open('all.csv','w')
f.write('port,europe\n')
f.close

f=open('all.csv','w')
f.write('port,USA\n')
f.close
```

etc.
I am fairly new in python. can someone help me how I can create a loop like this?

Comment: Note that opening a file with `'w'` truncates any existing file, hence that code would only save the last line written.

Comment: @yatici Use the `a+` mode.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to open and close the file several times.

Use regular expression `/(\w+)_\d{4}` (or more explicit `/(\w+)_\d{4}_info\.csv`) to extract the required part of the file paths in the list and [csv.writer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write to the csv file:

```
import re
import csv

a = ['/dir1/europe_2013_info.csv', '/dir2/USA_2013_info.csv', '/dir3/Africa_2013_info.csv']

regexp = '/(\w+)_\d{4}'
with open('all.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([['port', re.search(regexp, i).group(1)] for i in a])
```

then, the contents of `all.csv` will be:

```
port,europe
port,USA
port,Africa
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
import os.path

b=[os.path.basename(x).split('_')[0] for x in a]
with open('all.csv.', 'w') as f:
    for x in b:
        f.write('port,{0}\n'.format(b))
```

may do something similar to what you need.

Comment: FYI, it was missing an apostrophe and that messed up the code highlighting. I fixed it for you.